# Integration with Web Browsers

Tags: python, browser, integration

I am trying to make a download manager for Linux just like Internet Download Manager.

I wanted to know how does IDM integrate with the browsers without using any Extensions (Chrome) or Add-Ons (Firefox)
Also if i could know about the Overlay we say during a Video on the Browser (Download this Video).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that such program do use extensions and addons.

In fact I had a quick look at IDM which you mentioned, and it contains `IDMGCExt.crx` (chrome extension) and a `idmmzcc.xpi` (firefox addon), and some of the dlls are probably windows shell- and IE-extensions...

The only other way I can think of would be to write a [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI)-plugin, which would cover a lot of compatible browsers at once, but writing a program that interacts with a browser without any of these won't be possible with today's browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
But i still wonder, Why cant we see these extensions  and add-ons in the browsers,just like FDM's extensions and add-ons.